# This post does not meet our quality standards

Tags: support

I know what the problem is, but I am Norwegian and the spell check does it on Norwegian
so every word I write in English is wrong according to the spell check.
Please help. It is so annoying. it happens on Ubundu.com
Anyone got an idea on how to fix it?

Comment: Obfiouz torll si obveus

Comment: Stop being a bad poster.

Comment: How about instead you install additional dictionaries and switch languages? Jeg kan kjøre stavekontroll på Norsk helt fint..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two main points spring to mind:

1. There is no Stack Overflow [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) here.
2. Switch your dictionary to English.

I'm sorry but that's really the only response I can provide.

It may seem unfair, but SO is an English-language website and it may be that you need to find a friend who is more familiar with English to help you compose your post.

Comment: how do i switch?

Comment: Consult the documentation for your software.

Comment: @user132651: Your spellcheck is handled by your web browser, not by StackOverflow.